# Issue with Mongoose callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoosejs to insert data in my database. I am trying to add the save() callback seperately  example : 
new ModelName.save(saveData) instead of adding it there the conventional way.
new ModelName.save(function(err, model){...}

```
         var express = require('express');
          var router = express.Router();

        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var userDetail = mongoose.model('user_details');

        //not working
        router.post('/', resgisterUser);

        function resgisterUser(req, res) {
            new userDetail({
                    fullName: req.body.fullName,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    contactNumber: req.body.contactNumber,
                    password: req.body.password
                })
                .save(saveUserDetails);
        }

        function saveUserDetails(err, newUser) {
            console.log(newUser)
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end();
        }

       //working code

    function resgisterUser(req, res) {
        new userDetail({
                fullName: req.body.fullName,
                email: req.body.email,
                contactNumber: req.body.contactNumber,
                password: req.body.password
            })
            .save(function (err, newUser) {
                console.log(newUser)
                res.writeHead(200);
                res.end();
            });
    }

`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `saveUserDetails` function is defined outside of `resgisterUser(req, res)` scope, so doesn't have access to `req` and `res` objects.

Should be done this way:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userDetail = mongoose.model('user_details');

router.post('/', resgisterUser);

function resgisterUser(req, res) {
    function saveUserDetails(err, newUser) {
        console.log(newUser)
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    }

    new userDetail({
        fullName: req.body.fullName,
        email: req.body.email,
        contactNumber: req.body.contactNumber,
        password: req.body.password
    })
    .save(saveUserDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try moving your `saveUserDetails` function above your `registerUser` function. In JavaScript (really any language) it's considered bad practice to use a function before it is defined. On that node I'd also put your `registerUser` function above your route declaration as well.

Comment: moving up or down the function doesn't really matter, as mentioned by @svlapin the object is out of scope